# Rails Set a Cookie to ensure gets a Javascript message only once

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to set a cookie so that users only get a javascript only once. However, I am a Rails newbie and have no idea where to begin. Can anyone point in me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by this? What kind of javascript message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's Javascript you're concerned about I would manage the cookie entirely in Javascript. After the message is shown the first time, set the cookie. It's relatively easy to work with cookies in native Javascript, but libraries like this make it a no-brainer: http://code.google.com/p/cookies/ . You could also use localStorage.

Or you're talking about the inclusion of an actual script only one time? You could do this via Rails with a session ( http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails ), or just make that script a function that gets called or ignored based on whether a cookie has been set.